# Remove row from multidimensional array in jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, c#-5.0

I have a jagged array with a multidimensional array and want to remove an array inside the multidimensional array. My code is:

```
int[][,] arr = new int[4][,];

arr[0] = new int[,] { 
  { 1, 2, 3 }, // <- I want to remove this row 
  { 4, 5, 6 }, 
  { 5, 6, 7 }, 
  { 8, 9, 10 } };

arr[1] = new int[,] { 
  { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, 
  { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, 
  { 9, 10, 11, 12 }, 
  { 13, 14, 15, 16 } };

arr[2] = new int[,] { 
  { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 
  { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }, 
  { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 },
  { 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 } };

arr[3] = new int[,] { 
  { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 
  { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 
  { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 }, 
  { 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22 } };
      
int[,] removeArray = { { 1, 2, 3 } };
```

I tried to remove `{1, 2, 3}` from `arr[0]` by using *Linq*:

```
arr = arr
  .Where((val, i) => i != 0)
  .ToArray();
```

but this removes the *whole* `arr[0]` *row*. Does anyone know how I can get to remove `{1,2,3}` using *Linq*?

Comment: so you want to empty all elements in your remove list, but not the arrays that contain them?

Comment: unlike *jagged* array, multidimensional array *doesn't have* any inner arrays, that's why you can't remove them; all you can do is to recreate 2d array

Comment: yes. basically i just want to remove one array {1,2,3} from a[0]

Comment: @Valkyrie and do you also want to remove { 1, 2, 3 } any of the other places where they exist or only if it is exactly an identical array?

Comment: Your question is related to c# language version 5.0, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike *jagged* arrays, *multidimensional* ones doesn't consist of arrays:

```
int[][] jagged = new int[][] {
  new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, // <- this is an array
  new[] { 4, 5 },    // <- this is another array
};

int[,] array2D = new int[,] {
  { 1, 2, 3 },       // <- not an array
  { 4, 5, 6 },       // <- not an array 
};
```

So if you want to *"remove"* row from *2d array*, you have to recreate it; something like this:

```
private static T[,] RemoveRows<T>(T[,] source, T[] row) {
  if (row.Length != source.GetLength(1))
    return source;

  var keepRows = new List<int>(); 

  for (int r = 0; r < source.GetLength(0); ++r) 
    for (int c = 0; c < row.Length; ++c)
      if (!object.Equals(source[r, c], row[c])) {
        keepRows.Add(r);

        break;
      }

  if (keepRows.Count == source.Length)
    return source;

  T[,] result = new T[keepRows.Count, source.GetLength(1)];

  for (int r = 0; r < keepRows.Count; ++r)
    for (int c = 0; c < result.GetLength(1); ++c)
      result[r, c] = source[keepRows[r], c];

  return result;
}
```

and then

```
// we remove row; let it be 1d array, not 2d one
int[] removeArray = { 1, 2, 3 };

arr = arr
  .Select(array => RemoveRows(array, removeArray))
  .ToArray();
```

please, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QTMHUY) yourself